# trying to set up microservice/springboot/rabbitmq for a project here

Tags: java, spring

I was working on setting up the first service om my project which is productService (cars) everything was set up and I was about to test with postman to send to my localhost with /cars and for some reason I've gotten this error:

> {"timestamp":"2024-02-27T16:55:58.166+00:00","status":404,"error":"Not Found","path":"/cars"}

from postman. do note I have tried changing formatting etc. of the code with no help.

[image]

```
package Controllers;

import Cars.Car;
import Service.CarService;
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/cars")
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CarController {


    private CarService carServiceIMPL;

    @PostMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Car> addCar(@RequestBody Car car) {
        Car savedCar = carServiceIMPL.addCar(car);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(savedCar, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
}
```

https://github.com/ahadius/MikroExam/tree/main - github repo I'm using it on at the moment.

[image]

springboot itself runs pretty much fine and without any errors so I'm absolutely stuck here not understanding what's causing it.

I have used all help, from chatgpt to forums. I have searched up the error 404 and it seems small things can also cause this issue. the code inside GitHub is not big at all, feel free to look at it and replicate if you wish 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the controller you should be making a post request on the URL

```
http://localhost:8080/cars/cars
```

not

```
http://localhost:8080/cars
```

Because

```
@RequestMapping("/cars") + @PostMapping("/cars") = http://localhost:8080/cars/cars
```

If you do want to make a post request on the URL  `http://localhost:8080/cars` then you need to change your controller from

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/cars")
```

to

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/")
```

Because

```
@RequestMapping("/") + @PostMapping("/cars") = http://localhost:8080/cars
```

or

```
@RequestMapping("/cars") + @PostMapping( ) = http://localhost:8080/cars
```

or

```
@RequestMapping("/cars") + @PostMapping = http://localhost:8080/cars
```

Comment: thank you so much, i was literly smacking my head on the table entire day XD appriciate the quick response. and yes it worked.

Comment: Great! I'm glad you got it working Ahad